# aptana 2.0.5 & emmet plugin

Tags: aptana, emmet

after installing emmet (from http://emmet.io/eclipse/updates/ ) i received this message below:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Emmet for Eclipse 1.0.0.201303162055 (io.emmet.eclipse.feature.group 1.0.0.201303162055)
  Missing requirement: Emmet for Eclipse 1.0.0.201303162055 (io.emmet.eclipse 1.0.0.201303162055) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.expressions 3.4.300' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Emmet for Eclipse 1.0.0.201303162055 (io.emmet.eclipse.feature.group 1.0.0.201303162055)
    To: io.emmet.eclipse [1.0.0.201303162055]
```

With `aptana 3.0` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it doesn’t work in Aptana 2.0 since it’s Eclipse core is very outdated. Try to use latest Eclipse and install Aptana as plugin into it

Answer (score 0):

Just update your [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download)！ , then it will work better:)